# Why are TF-IDF vocabulary words represented as axes/dimensions?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf

I want an **intuitive** way for understanding why each word in a TF-IDF vocabulary are represented as separate dimensions.

**Why can't I just add the TF-IDF values of all the words together and use that as a representation of the document?**

I have a basic understanding of why we do this. 
*Apples =/= Oranges*.
But apparently I don't know it well enough to convince someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately all of NLP is arbitrary. If you wanted to add up the tf-idf values for all words in a phrase/sentence/document and found the resulting number useful for some task you were trying to do you are free to do so. But that number probably won't be very useful for most standard NLP tasks such as search, summarization, sentiment analysis, etc.  It's hard to represent the meaning of a phrase/sentence/document with a single number.

By representing a phrase/sentence/document as a vector which has a separate row for each word in your vocabulary, you can leverage vector/matrix algebra to represent some standard operations you might want to do when solving NLP problems. For example, you could compute the cosine similarity between the vectors representing 2 documents and use that to judge how similar those 2 documents are.

Something else you might be interested in: There is an NLP concept called word2vec which lets you represent every word as a different vector of numbers and then lets you add/subtract them to discover semantic relations between them.

For example, it might say

```
king - man + woman ≈ queen
```

You can read more about this at https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/21/the-amazing-power-of-word-vectors/